# Communication between two ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, asp.net-identity

I have one ASP.NET MVC 5 application wherein I have implemented ASP.NET Identity. That is, all stuff related to Login, Registration, Edit User, Manage Users, etcs has been implemented there.
Now there is another MVC 5 application where I want to consume the User account related activities from the above MVC 5 application. (Similar to single signon).

How can I implement this kind of architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Configure both applications to point to the same database for the membership information used by ASP.NET Identity and then [configure both applications to share cookies as described in this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb0zx8fc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).